# how to check the size of the stack memory using a program in c#

Tags: c#, memory, stack, limit, stack-overflow

I have tried many means but there are ways to find when a stack overflow occurs but there is no program which determines the actual limit of the stack

Comment: In Visual Studio, where is a "Call stack" window. You can check the order of calls at any time, if you hit a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You're right; there is indeed not a good way to determine this. But: if you're using enough of the stack for it to matter, *something is probably already very wrong*.

There are two common scenarios involving stack overflow:

- recursion, which can usually be replaced by a non-recursive loop, sometimes involving a  `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>` as a placeholder (assuming that it isn't an inadvertent buggy infinite recursion for no good reason - a very common error)
- oversized locals, in particular excessive use of `stackalloc` for non-trivial payloads (the latter of which can often be replaced with an `ArrayPool<T>` lease, perhaps after checking for non-trivial payload size)

On the latter, there *has been* discussion around a notional API for "give me a span of some kind, but let the runtime decide whether to use stackalloc or a lease or an isolated array, based on the size and the amount of space left in the stack", but: it has not been implemented to date.

Additionally, note that using lots of stack space can be more expensive than you think; although a large stack might be allocated, this is *virtual* memory, and doesn't necessarily need *actual* memory until it gets used for the first time; so: planning to use lots of stack space can force *actual* memory allocation of the stack area, which can then never be reclaimed.

So to summarize, again: no, there isn't really a good way to do that, but *if you want it*, you're probably doing something wrong.